# My sewer pipe makes a huge noise when flushed. Can that damage the pipe?

Tags: noise, sewer

The sewer pipe on my building makes a huge noise whenever someone flushes the toilet. 
Apparently there is not enough air input in the pipe and whenever someone flushes the toilet this causes vacuum and noise.
I assume that with the noise there is also vibration. Can this cause  permanaent damage on the pipe?

Answer (score 1):

It's unlikely to damage your pipe, but the problem could be air in the system. You may have an old pipe underground that has a break in it.